# How do I add UV coordinates to a procedurally generated texture?

Tags: normals, baking

I have set up this decent normal map for a beaten metal, but I have a slight stretching on the model.
Note that the texture is 3D.
I don't know why there is this stretching: the object is in scale 1 on all axis.
So as a final solution (and to learn how to do it) I was thinking to just bake the generated normal map on an image, so that I can get control over it with the UV unwrap (which I already made).
Spent a couple hours in tinkering and searching, but couldn't find how to do this...

[image: generated normal map]

Comment: Hello :). The stretching probably happens because procedural textures are using generated coords by default :). Use different coords (object/uv) and a mapping node to correct it :).

Comment: I don't know how to do that...

Comment: No problem, I'll post an answer :)

Comment: Thank you VERY much, Jachym :)

Comment: guys he actually asking 2 questions, one what says the title, and second the strecthing problem...

Comment: Eh, just because I thought that that was the solution... I edited the title question, hope it's ok now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Noise Texture uses *Generated coordinates*, which often cause stretching.
You have three ways to correct it:

1. Use a *Mapping node* to correct the stretching
2. Use your *UV map* coordinates
3. Use *Object coordinates*

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Though I can't understand why a 3D noise generated on a model scaled 1,1,1 would distort!

Comment: Well, *generated coordinates* range from 0.0 to 1.0 over the entire length of the mesh. So unless your mesh is a 1:1:1 cube, it will be distorted. *Object coordinates* are more useful in many cases.